# How to repeat html div depending on data

Tags: jquery

I am very new to this. I have a `<div><h2><label id="AC">3JD</label></h2></div>`. I want to repeat that depending on data.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(alltask).Tasks;        
    $.each(obj, function(i, val){
        document.getElementById("AC").innerHTML = val.Air;
    });     
}
```

If it returns 4 diff. AC. I want to show it 4 times. As of now, it's showing the last AC from that each loop.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall be as you are writing the code, check the below

```
var htmlString = '<div><h2><label id="AC{1}">{0}</label></h2></div>';
var FinalHtml="";
var obj = $.parseJSON(alltask).Tasks;        
    $.each(obj, function(i, val){
      FinalHtml = FinalHtml + htmlString.Replace('{0}',val.Air).Replace('{1}',i.toString());
    });     
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to repeat IDs, you can declare integer var and use for instead of for each, your html string will be  var htmlString = '<div><h2><label id="AC{1}">{0}</label></h2></div>'; then in the replace you will provide the loop counter

Comment: Do I need to do anything to add this to the page?

Comment: Build the htmlString inside the each loop, increment the ID in there with the `i` from the `$.each`